# ag row group moves when scrolling

Tags: css, ag-grid

I had a grid table with two group rows. The second one always moves and covers the next row when I scroll the table.

Before I scroll:

[image]

After I scroll:

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the DOM of the group row.

[image]

The ag-grid version is 18.1.1 and everything was just fine when I were in v16. The browser is chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I did not update the ag-grid in a proper way (I downloaded the ag-grid zip file and recover it in my node_modules manually).

Problem solved by using npm (yarn) command to update.